# SharePoint Online how to publish two lists on one site programatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, application-pages

If I start doing a lists on SharePoint Online and try to add them I only see my surname and name. I can't see lists or libraries. How to add to a page list on library by code programatically to SharePoint Online site.

Please see this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more detailed information about the issue?

If you want to add the list into the page programmatically, you could refer to the articles below.

[How To Add WebPart To A Page In SharePoint Office 365 Programmatically Using C# Client Side Object Model (CSOM).](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Add-WebPart-to-a-Page-in-SharePoint-Office-365-Programmatically-using-C-Client-Side-Object-Model-(CSOM))

[SharePoint 2013 – Remove, Add and Update List View Web Parts on publishing pages programmatically.](https://veenstra.me.uk/2015/03/30/sharepoint-2013-remove-add-and-update-list-view-web-parts-on-publishing-pages-programmatically/)

Comment: I have problem to show list which has been added in creator, but how to show in the page that list created in Visual Studio Creator